# Sending data to HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to loop through the data ,grab it in a variable and then send it to HighCharts

but I am unable to do it 
Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
  data : { 'perfid': valueOne, 'hostname': $("#host").val(), 'iteration': valueThree},
  success: function(data) {
    $('#img1').hide();

   var obj = data[$("#host").val()].iscsi_lif.result.sectoutput.sect;

    for(var key in obj) {

            var avg_latency = parseInt(obj[key].avg_latency);
            i++;
            console.log(avg_latency);           
    }


    $('#graphcontainer2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Write Latencies'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Write Latencies(us)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Write Latencies: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Write latency',
        data: [ 
                ['Average Latency', parseInt(avg_latency)],
              ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Here is the screenshot of console values of avg_latency :
[image]

I want to display graph of all avg_latencies.
Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong in this code.
Thanks.

Comment: You should pass an array of your data to the highchart data, but it sounds that you're passing a single data.

Comment: @VahidMsm I tried array, but it the display but noting is displayed after trying to pass an array, can you please post a jsFiddle for this ?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a list of your data in dictionary to the highchart series, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
  data : { 'perfid': valueOne, 'hostname': $("#host").val(), 'iteration': valueThree},
  success: function(data) {
    $('#img1').hide();

   var obj = data[$("#host").val()].iscsi_lif.result.sectoutput.sect;
    var my_data_list = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
            var avg_latency = parseInt(obj[key].avg_latency);
            my_data_list.push({name: 'Average Latency', y: parseInt(avg_latency)});
            console.log(avg_latency);           
    }


    $('#graphcontainer2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Write Latencies'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Write Latencies(us)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Write Latencies: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Write latency',
        data: my_data_list,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: It works now :)
Thanks I understood how to pass data as series.

You made one person happy today @VahidMsm